# Interactive heat map in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, excel, flex3, csv, heatmap

I’m at a very basic level with Flex and with programming in general. I am working on a project where I have data in an Excel (.csv) format, it’s a large Excel plot/matrix where each cell has a temperature number. I want to import this matrix into Flex somehow, or parse the data in Flex, so that this matrix turns into an interactive heat with colors corresponding to varying temperatures from blue (cold) to red (hot), and each spot on roll over shows the temperature number.

If you have any suggestions or point me in the right direction as to where I can start I’ll really appreciate it.

- Should I use plot charts, or some other control?
- should I convert data into XML or import into a MySQL database, would that be easier for Flex? But then, again, the data is basically just a large matrix, there's no headers/ fields in a traditional database sense, just many cells each having a temperature number.
- Also, would you have any suggestions how I can import the data into Flex and use it as data provider to plot the heat map?

I’ll really appreciate your help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are some examples that cover these requirements in [Tour de Flex](http://flex.org/tour).  You can use custom item renderers in a DataGrid to achieve the different colors.  Tooltips will provide the roll-overs.